# How to get data from Google's Report API in stream

Tags: google-drive-api, google-admin-sdk

I'm using the following code to get `drive` log data from `ReportsAPI`:

```
SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.reports.audit.readonly']
DELEGATION_ACCT = 'xxx'
creds = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(self._config['googletools']
                                                                      ['credentials-file'],
                                                                      scopes=SCOPES)
delegate_creds = creds.with_subject(DELEGATION_ACCT)
service = build('admin', 'reports_v1', credentials=delegate_creds)
drive_logs = service.activities().list(userKey='all', applicationName='drive').execute()
```

And that returns me a list of `drive` logs.

I would like to get the same result but from stream, so that I could get the logs in a continues way

Comment: Could you specify please what you mean with "from stream, so that I could get the logs in a continues way"? You want to retrieve the logs one by one with a loop or something?

Comment: @ziganotschka I would like to get the logs continuously - meaning that I'll connect once and will already read the newest logs